# iOS app stops working, profile is deleted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm currently developing an app for iOS using swift and I've noticed recently that after I install the app on my iPhone, it will work for some time but after a bit it just won't launch anymore and the profile under General > Profiles & Device Management > has been deleted and I have to plug my phone to my computer to re-run it.

Is there a particular reason why this would happen or is there a way around this?

Edit: I have not yet bought a developer membership, I simply wanted to know if there is a way without it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the build that you have on your phone has a limit to the amount of time that the Development profile is available on your device. It's usually up to 5 days or so, (if it's significantly shorter than that, you may have an issue) so that you can take your device home and play with it if need be and return to the office and fix any issues you find.

I'm not actually sure that there is any way to lengthen this development build time but yes that's why it won't reopen and why you'd have to re-install your application to a device to continue to test. I think it has something to do with the Apple Developers Provisioning Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you have not bought a developer program membership? I'm pretty sure that when you install an app to your phone using the free trial membership, you get this time limit on your wildcard profile.

The "way around it" is to attach the phone to the computer and build and run on the device again.

Comment: I probably should mentioned but yes I do not have the membership yet. Preferably, I would have wanted to wait before my app is ready to be released or to have a mvp that is ready for use before buying the membership. I'm still at the point of testing it out and was wondering if there is a way to keep it on my phone without having to re-install it every other day.

Comment: Yes, that way would be to buy the membership. Otherwise, the profile will expire quite rapidly. Life is compromise, and this is the compromise you've chosen! Nothing wrong with that.